# Android zoom/scale image in coordinator layout

Tags: android, scrollview, parallax, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have issue and i don't how to solve it.
So, how to make ImageView in CollapsingToolbar overscrollable?
For example,

```
CoordinatorLayout
 -- AppBarLayout
   -- CollapsingToolbarLayout
       ----30% Non visible part----
       ----40% Visible part, center of image----
       ----30% Non visible part----
 --NestedScrollView <-- Here content
```

How to make when user fling down by image, make image visible part of image bigger? I tried to wrap imageview into scrollview and make overscroll, but image is cropped.
Any ideas?

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="view.utils.FlingBehavior"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/white"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <!-- In this block my imageview and two textviews -->
            <view.DetailsTopBlock
                android:id="@+id/details_review_top_block"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_320" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:visibility="visible">
        <!-- content here-->
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: Any progress with that issue?